# How to resolve "input must be under 256 bytes" in android?

Tags: java, android, encryption, android-keystore

I want to store my secrete token using keystore. currently i first create the key using alias that encrypt the token and than decrypt. But **cipherOutputStream.close();** my app crash and show below error.
**"input must be under 256 bytes"**. i am passing long token "xwejdg3kcbkgkv6858gj69gfldkxserhijhgdfsdffgrjkejbvffdfsdd........"
I google to much but i didn't found suitable answer. Any one can help me how i can change my code.

```
createNewKeys(strAlias, getActivity());
encryptString(strtoken, strAlias, this);

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    public static void createNewKeys(String strAlis, Context context) {
        String alias = strAlis.toString();
        try {
            // Create new key if needed
            if (!keyStore.containsAlias(alias)) {
                Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
                end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
                KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
                        .setAlias(alias)
                        .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=Sample Name, O=Android Authority"))
                        .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                        .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                        .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                        .build();
                KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
                generator.initialize(spec);
                KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        refreshKeys();
    }

    public static String encryptString(String token, String alias, Context context) {
        try {
            KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
            RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey();
            String initialText = token;
            Log.e("MessageApp=", ""+initialText.toString());
            Cipher inCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "AndroidOpenSSL");
            inCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(outputStream, inCipher);
            cipherOutputStream.write(initialText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            cipherOutputStream.close();//Error in this line

            byte[] values = outputStream.toByteArray();
            encryptedText = Base64.encodeToString(values, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "encryptString Exception " + e.getMessage() + " occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
                  return encryptedText;
    }


 public static void decryptString(String encryptedText, String alias) {
        try {
            KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
            Cipher output = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            output.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey());

            String cipherText = encryptedText.toString();
            CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT)), output);
            ArrayList<Byte> values = new ArrayList<>();
            int nextByte;
            while ((nextByte = cipherInputStream.read()) != -1) {
                values.add((byte) nextByte);
            }

            byte[] bytes = new byte[values.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                bytes[i] = values.get(i).byteValue();
            }

            decryptedText = new String(bytes, 0, bytes.length, "UTF-8");

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good naming is a large part of the documentation (since there is no explicit documentation) and understandability.

Answer (score 1):

To encrypt more bytes than the modulus (- 11 bytes for PKCS#1 v1.5 padding) then you need to use a hybrid crypto-system. So you should encrypt an AES key and use that for the streaming mode.

Unlike the ECB (incorrectly) indicates, RSA really doesn't use multiple blocks. So you cannot use it for streaming unless you keep to one single block.

Comment: @zaph Any specific language agnostic encryption topics you'd like to cover (apologies about this off topicness, will delete)?

Comment: @zaph Not sure about those topics. Programming should be involved, otherwise it would be better suited to the security & crypto sites. Furthermore, password authentication handling is cryptography, not encryption.